# Compare two arrays of objects excluding a property using lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am able to get the difference between two arrays of objects using **_.differenceWith** like this:

```
_.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, _.isEqual)
```

Suppose I have `arr1` and `arr2` as:

```
    let arr1= [
      {
        id:1,
        val1:{
          pre:1,
          foo:2
        }
      }
      ]

    let arr2= [
      {
        id:3,
        val1:{
          pre:1,
          foo:2
        }
      },
      ]
```

The `id`s are different, but the `val1` properties are same.

So, I want to compare the arrays excluding `id`.

How can I achieve this using lodash or simple JS?

Comment: `So, I want to compare the arrays excluding id.`  So what if later you add `val2`, or some other property?,  as the accepted answer will fail there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `_.differenceWith()` comparator function to compare the `val1` property of the objects:

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":1,"val1":{"pre":1,"foo":2}}]
const arr2 = [{"id":3,"val1":{"pre":1,"foo":2}}]

const result = _.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, (a, b) => _.isEqual(a.val1, b.val1))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_.omit` to omit id in when doing isEqual..

eg.

```js
let arr1= [
  {id:1, val1:{ pre:1, foo:2 }},
  {id: 4, val1: { pre: 3, addThis: 'just to check' }}
];

let arr2= [{ id:3, val1:{ pre:1, foo:2 }}];

console.log(_.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, (a, b) => {
  return _.isEqual(
    _.omit(a, ['id']),
    _.omit(b, ['id'])
  )
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```